# JavaFX create alert and get result

Tags: java, javafx, dialog, alert

For my CS class they require us to use JavaFX alerts. I can make an alert appear, but how do I get what button was clicked? What would be the best way to go about getting this data?

Also if possible, I'd like to make it have a drop down panel and when the user selects and option the alert closes and prints what the user selected.

Here's some example code that I have. When I click one of the buttons, it just closes the dialog.

```java
Alert a = new Alert(AlertType.NONE, "Promote pawn to:", new ButtonType("Queen"), new ButtonType("Rook"));
a.setTitle("Title");
a.setHeaderText("My header text");
a.setResizable(true);
a.setContentText("Content text");
a.showAndWait();
```

Thanks,

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html)?

Comment: I tried. I don't understand what it's saying. How does the result converter work? If I could see an example of actual code I think I could figure it out, but I've been looking around and haven't found anything about alerts besides displaying them and setting their type.

Comment: There are three examples under "Option 1", "Option 2" and "Option 3". AIUI you don't use the result converter for an `Alert`.

Comment: The `Dialog<R>` documentation says  "A result converter must always be set, whenever the type `R` is not Void or ButtonType.", but `Alert` extends `Dialog<ButtonType>` so the result converter doesn't apply.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
ButtonType queen = new ButtonType("Queen");
ButtonType rook = new ButtonType("Rook");
Alert a = new Alert(AlertType.NONE, "Promote pawn to:", queen, rook);
a.setTitle("Title");
a.setHeaderText("My header text");
a.setResizable(true);
a.setContentText("Content text");
a.showAndWait().ifPresent(response -> {
    if (response == queen) {
        // promote to queen...
    } else if (response == rook) {
        // promote to rook...
    }
});
```

Comment: Explains it perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: It's really just taken directly from the docs (basically "Option 2" verbatim), so I'm not sure what you were missing, but glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

İf you want to do it with Non-Blocking type of code:

```java
final Alert alert2 = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
alert2.show();
alert2.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<DialogEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(DialogEvent event) {
        ButtonType result=alert2.getResult();
        String resultText=result.getText();
        //result logic
    }
});
```